# Is the same source code compiled (into CorDapps) at different times considered different versions?

Tags: corda

Something that was highlighted in a discussion today. The same CorDapp (same source code no difference) was deployed in both Party A and B. However, the CorDapp in party A was compiled a week ago. When party B tried to create a transaction with A, it doesn't work and you get an exception as net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionverificationException$ContractCOnstraintRejection@: Contract constraints failed for net-corda.training.contract.IOUContract, transaction: tx hash. Is this a valid observation?

The log outputs the following exception using the IOUContract as an example:
`net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractConstraintRejection: Contract constraints failed for net.corda.training.contract.IOUContract, transaction: D60DD71F9D50BA7A638455B676CD394601460D937544A5697643FDD952C9FCB4
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verifyConstraints(LedgerTransaction.kt:91) ~[corda-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verify(LedgerTransaction.kt:67) ~[corda-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.transactions.InMemoryTransactionVerifierService$verify$1.invoke(InMemoryTransactionVerifierService.kt:13) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.transactions.InMemoryTransactionVerifierService$verify$1.invoke(InMemoryTransactionVerifierService.kt:10) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:104) ~[corda-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt) ~[corda-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:116) ~[corda-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22) ~[corda-core-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]`

Answer (score 1):

One missing question is:

Was the same cordapp-jar distributed to both machines ? By this I don't mean the same source code distributed and then compiled independently, I mean one compilation and then the result of that ran on both nodes. Before Corda reaches wire stability, any differences in the compilation environment (no matter how minor) may result in errors like the one you encountered.

Comment: The error I had posted was from the jar I had compiled on my machine actually. I compiled the first jar, copied out the entire build to another location, spun up the nodes to make sure it works. Next I ran deployNodes again to compile another set of the nodes. This time round, I had copied the plugin from participant C and replace it with that on that build folder which I had copied out earlier.

Comment: A bit on the context: It all started when we had wanted to show that transacting parties cannot unilaterally make alterations to the flow codes. We took the IOU repo, made alterations to the settle flow and overwritten the plugin for participant C in a another build folder which we have prepared earlier. Of course there was a flow exception error, though it wasn't what we had expected. So we restored the IOU repo by deleting and cloning again.

Comment: We copied the plugin file back to C and it showed the same error, so we decide to investigate. Problem is that the error message doesn't tell us much unfortunately. (Nice avatar by the way!)

Comment: Hmm... I would have to ensure that all the jar files are exactly the same on all machines (for now).. You can use `sum` or `cksum` to generate a basic hash for checking the binaries are all identical

Answer (score 0):

As Richard states, for a given set of CorDapp source files, the hash of the generated CorDapp JAR is not deterministic.

One key reason is that the JAR still includes a timestamp. See https://docs.corda.net/head/cordapp-build-systems.html#creating-the-cordapp-jar.